# Image file details being displayed while using bootstrap carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm building a rails 4 app that includes an image carousel on the show page.  The images have been uploaded via paperclip and imagemagick.  The first (primary) image is attached to one model (listings), and the next 5 images are associated with a second model "assets", and are housed within an array.

The upload is working, and the images are displaying in the carousel, however the image file details (file name, asset_file_size, created_at, etc) are showing up below the images when I display images from the assets array. My view code is:

```
      <div id="show-page-carousel" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
            <center><img src= <%= @listing.image.url(:medium) %> alt="" ></center>
          </div>

          <%= @listing.assets.each do |asset| %> 
            <div class="item">
              <center><img src= <%= asset.asset.url(:medium) %> alt="" ></center>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#show-page-carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#show-page-carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
      </div>
```

The image file details that appear under the images in the bootstrap carousel look like:

```
[#<Asset id: 3, asset_file_name: "cathat1", asset_content_type: "application/octet-stream", asset_file_size: 79746, asset_updated_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:15", listing_id: 102, created_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:17", updated_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:17">, #<Asset id: 4, asset_file_name: "cathat7", asset_content_type: "application/octet-stream", asset_file_size: 74176, asset_updated_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:16", listing_id: 102, created_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:17", updated_at: "2013-11-24 21:23:17">]
```

What am I doing incorrectly while calling the asset block?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with using <%= for the block:

```
<%= @listing.assets.each do |asset| %>
```

After changing to <% , the text disappeared.